# Lazy initialization error with parameter

Tags: c#, class, parameters, lazy-initialization

I am coding a MVC internet application and have a question in regards to lazy initialization.

Here is my working code before lazy initialization:

Declaration:

```
private ValidationService validationService;
```

Initialization:

```
validationService = new ValidationService(genericMultipleRepository);
```

Here is the code I am trying:

Declaration:

```
private Lazy<ValidationService> validationService;
```

Initialization:

```
validationService = new Lazy<ValidationService>(genericMultipleRepository);
```

Here is the error:

> Error 125 The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Lazy.Lazy(System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode)'
>   has some invalid
>   arguments

I have looked at the [`Lazy<T> constructor documentation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642329.aspx), but I don't see what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor of lazy expects a `Func` that returns the `ValidationService` type specified:

```
validationService = new Lazy<ValidationService>
                    ( () => new ValidationService(genericMultipleRepository)
                    );
```

That would be equivalent to:

```
validationService = new Lazy<ValidationService>
                    ( SomeMethod
                    );

private ValidationService SomeMethod()
{
    return new ValidationService(this.genericMultipleRepository);
}
```

Note you can't pass the parameter `genericMultipleRepository` like it is inferred by using the lambda expression.